# How to resolve NewAD error with -Path $OU

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to automate the creation of new users on my Active Directory.

However when I run my powershell here is the error that presents itself to me :

```
New-ADUser: Unable to validate argument on "Path" parameter. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty and try again.
At character Line: 23:19
+ -Path $ OR `
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo: InvalidData: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: ParameterArgumentValidationError, Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

What can i do ?

Thanks for your help !

This is my code

```
   $ADUsers = Import-csv E:\SCRIPT\newusers.csv

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{

       $Username    = $User.username
       $Password    = $User.password
       $Firstname   = $User.firstname
       $Lastname    = $User.lastname
       $Description = $User.description
       $OU          = $User.ou
              New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $Username `
            -UserPrincipalName "$Lastname@domaine.fr" `
            -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
            -GivenName $Firstname `
            -Surname $Lastname `
            -Enabled $True `
            -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False `
            -DisplayName "$Lastname, $Firstname" `
            -Description $Description `
            -AccountPassword $Password `
            -Path $OU `
   }
```

Comment: That would indicate that one or more users don't have an `ou` value in the CSV

Comment: [1] try turning on powershell strict mode = `Get-Help Set-StrictMode`. that will give you an error if you try to use `$User.ou` when there is no such property. ///// [2] take a look at splatting = `Get-Help about_Splatting`. that will let you avoid the messy backticks. [*grin*]

Comment: Here is the content of my .csv : username;password;firstname;lastname;description;ou
snat;lbcN4t1v3llbc;Ste;Nat;Developpeur;OU=LBC-USERS,DC=lbcdom,DC=local

Comment: I have this error message now @Lee_Dailey : New-ADUser: Directory object not found
At character Line: 12: 1
+ New-ADUser `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (CN = \\, CN = Steve ... lbcdom, DC = local: String) [New-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: ActiveDirectoryCmdlet: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException, Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Comment: @Yarka - [1] **_please_**, add your full error msg to the Question & wrap it in code formatting markers. that will let folks both FIND it and READ it easily. [*grin*] ///// [2] from what little i can read of your error msg, it seems that you have an invalid OU name. i recommend you try replacing your call with a call to show the value of the call on-screen so that you compare it with what you _expect_ it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment indicates the CSV file uses the `;` semi-colon as delimiter character, but you neglect to add that to the `Import-Csv` cmdlet. Now it is trying to parse the data using the default comma `,` and because of that **none** of the fields have a correct value.

Replace the first line with

```
$ADUsers = Import-csv -Path 'E:\SCRIPT\newusers.csv' -Delimiter ';'
```

Other than that, have a look at using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting), so you don't need those awkward backticks.